# Want to hide a table row containing zero in qty

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: p]

Want to hide the table row containing Zero in the qty column. I had hard-coded the items and quantity value is coming from $post of another form. Want to hide it using java script or jquery.

Comment: Iterate over each row, find the value of the input box, if it's 0, hide the row.

Comment: i'll give you a head start: `$('tr').each()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery `.filter()` and `.closest()` methods like so:

```js
$('.table input').filter(function() { return +this.value === 0; }).closest("tr").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Qty: <input type="text" name="somename" value="2">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Qty: <input type="text" name="somename" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Qty: <input type="text" name="somename" value="8">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Qty: <input type="text" name="somename" value="78">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Qty: <input type="text" name="somename" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Qty: <input type="text" name="somename" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Say your inputs have a class `class="qty"` with `value="0"`

- Use the Attribute Selector `[]` to match all inputs having `[value="0"]`
- Than traverse to ancestors using `.closest()`:

```js
$('.qty[value="0"]').closest("tr").hide()
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Qty: <input class="qty" type="text" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Qty: <input class="qty" type="text" value="4">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Qty: <input class="qty" type="text" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td").each(function(){
   var storeData = $("input").val();
   if(storeData == 0){
      $(this).parent().hide();
   }
  });
```

Comment: Could you please provide some explanation and context on why this code answers the OP's question?